# Construct JSON in proper format

Tags: javascript, json

My JSON have current and targeted items.

Targeted item will remain same for the rest of the year, currently i am repeating for all the months

so i am asking experts is there a better way??

it is working fine , but i am thinking any alternative way in less json

```
{
  "DataContainer": {
    "profit": [
      {
        "current": "20",
        "target": "19"
      },
      {
        "current": "20",
        "target": "19"
      },
      {
        "current": "30",
        "target": "19"
      },
      {
        "current": "23",
        "target": "19"
      },
      {
        "current": "19",
        "target": "19"
      },
      {
        "current": "17",
        "target": "19"
      }
    ],
    "revenue": [
      {
        "current": "50",
        "target": "45"
      },
      {
        "current": "20",
        "target": "45"
      },
      {
        "current": "30",
        "target": "45"
      },
      {
        "current": "23",
        "target": "45"
      },
      {
        "current": "19",
        "target": "45"
      },
      {
        "current": "17",
        "target": "45"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem much point in repeating *target* if it's the same value for each pair, why not something like:

```
{
  "DataContainer": {
    "profit": {"current": ["20","20","30","23","19","17"], "target": "19"},
    "revenue":{"current": ["50","20","30","23","19","17"], "target": "45"}
  }
}
```

or

```
{
  "DataContainer": {
    "profit": {"current": "20 20 30 23 19 17", "target": "19"},
    "revenue":{"current": "50 20 30 23 19 17", "target": "45"}
  }
}
```

But I have no idea what you are using this for.